# PHP variables as arguments when using exec

Tags: php

I have a very basic website that I am using purely to improve my web development skills. I have just began using PHP in order to process the input of forms that the user has filled out. The script is supposed to take the data from the form then use the Pushbullet API to send the entered data to my phone. I am making use of the exec function to run a bash script I placed in the /usr/bin directory called pushmsg. This script takes three arguments, which are the three pieces of information from the form. The problem is, the three variables do not appear to work when placed inside the exec function. The message is sent to my phone, but only the header that it sends by default with the pushmsg command without the data entered.

Here is the code:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $core = $_POST["core"];
    exec('pushmsg echo $name echo $phone echo $core');
    ?>
    <h1>request submited successfully</h1>
    <p>thanks for sending yout request, <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>.<br>
    a text will be sent to <?php echo $_POST["phone"]; ?> once your details have been confirmed.
    </p>
    <div class="center">
    <button class="button" action="/index.html">home page</button>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Also, I am aware it isn't particularly safe to use the exec function with user input, but this website isn't going to be public any time in the near future, so I will deal with that when I need to.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try using double quotes and removing echo from exec

Comment: And for the love of God, validate the `$_POST` data before using it!

Comment: That did it, thanks @shashi! And I will look into it, as I said at the bottom, when I publish the website @fubar.

Comment: might want to look at  `escapeshellarg`   http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php, and/or `escapeshellcmd` http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php  I wouldn't put security off, because it's not going live for some time.  These things are easy to forget later and it's better to secure it and know it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend writing the command into a PHP variable and then using that as the command itself:

```
$command = "pushmsg echo $name echo $phone echo $core";
$output = exec($command);
```

You can catch the last line of the output of `exec` in the `$output` variable. Or use `shell_exec` to catch the full output of the command.

```
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$core = $_POST["core"];
$command = "pushmsg echo $name echo $phone echo $core";
$output = exec($command);
?>
<h1>request submited successfully</h1>
<p>thanks for sending yout request, <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>.<br>
a text will be sent to <?php echo $_POST["phone"]; ?> once your details have been confirmed.
</p>
<div class="center">
<button class="button" action="/index.html">home page</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to

```
$command = "pushmsg $name $phone $core";
$output = exec($command);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @shashi and @mstruebing pointed out, I simply needed to replace the single quotes with doubles. This made it work fine. I also removed the echos, as they weren't supposed to be there in the first place. The replacement, if anyone is interested:

```
    old: exec('pushmsg echo $name echo $phone echo $core');
    new:  exec("pushmsg echo $name $phone $core");
```

Thanks.